# Regular Expression to exclude files

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to write some regular expressions for a FTP operation wherein the job should

1. Poll multiple folders starting only with alphabets. The home drive contains folders starting with '..' and hence cd .. takes it back.
2. Exclude any files that start with '.' or 'local'
3. Pick files that do not end with a particular string. On this one I wrote an expression but found that it does not works for all cases.

Can anyone suggest a water tight expression to say, not pick files ending with ABC and XYZ?

Comment: Can you post the experssion you tried?

Comment: Also please tag or post what language you are working in.

Comment: I want not to pick any file that starts with ABC, BCA or CAB and ends with XYZ or YZX. for this i wrote this exp ^((?!(ABC|BCA|CAB).*.(XYZ|YZX)).)*$ It worked for most of the cases but failed for couple of them. But my main concern are the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work: `[a-zA-Z][\S]*^(ABC|XYZ)` but Im not 100% sure of all the details of your requirements. What the regex should be saying is anything that starts with an alphabetic letter and then has as many non-white space characters as it wants and then does NOT end in ABC or XYZ.

Comment: `^(ABC|XYZ)` wouldn't do what you think it is doing.

Comment: So what does it do? I wasnt really sure about that part.

Comment: It is basically an invalid regex to use `^` in between which is used for start of input or for negation inside character class.

Comment: can anyone answer the second condition please?

Comment: @user2479093 Oh yeah, sorry, forgot about that. I think your easiest method would be to find all the files that match what you dont want (starts with . or local and ends with ABC) and just pick everything but that. The regex to find those files would be: `^(\.|local)\w*(ABC|XYZ)$`.

Comment: @Dgrin91 It doesn't works  and i think it is incorrect as i don't want to pick any file starting with '.' or local whereas your exp will only pick files starting with them.

Comment: @user2479093 Right, that is the point. You basically approach the problem from the other side - you find all the ones that *are* '.' or "local" and ignore all of those. Then you do all of your work on all the ones you didn't find.